# How can I force windows to never open maximized?

Tags: ubuntu

I have seen solutions for forcing windows to be opened maximized but never anything which would prevent windows from being opened maximized. Is this something that can only be done for a specific application or can I generally prevent windows from being opened maximized? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use devilspie. Install it with `sudo apt install devilspie`, if you are on Debian/Ubuntu/etc. On RedHat/CentOS/etc., you will have to install RPM package (https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=devilspie, search on http://rpm.pbone.net/).

Take a look at this question and answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized. You can use the instructions from the link to make devilspie work, and use an action `unmaximize` instead of `maximize`. I see no point of repeating the whole procedure for devilspie here.

Another option would be to unmaximize all windows with a command. The following line unmaximizes all open windows:

```
for i in $(wmctrl -l | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs); do wmctrl -i -r $i -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz; done
```

Or make a file unmaximize.ds with the content:

```
(unmaximize)
```

Then run

```
devilspie -a unmaximize.ds
```

The problem with the last solution is that devilspie will continue running, if you want it just to be executed once for all open windows.

Comment: This is useful, and yes my use case is not a once off 'unmaximize', but general prevention of maximization. My specific issue was with libre office programs opening full screen. It seems that when  the document window initially is opened it tries to maximize, then devilspie stops that, but then later maximizes anyway before I get control of the program. Is there a configuration file I can change perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you could have a script with wmctrl running all the time in an endless loop, executing unmaximize every few seconds. Instead of `wmctrl -l | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs`, from the answer you could run `wmctrl -l | grep Libre | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs`, and unmaximize only LibreOffice windows. In that, way second maximize, which is not detected with devilspie, would be neutralized.